# emacs with nrepl.el for Clojure - how to hide a popup buffer?

Tags: emacs, clojure, popup, buffer, aquamacs

I'm using emacs 23 (acquamacs) and have installed [nrepl.el](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el).

I've evaluated some Clojure code with

```
C-c C-p
```

(this key combo is to Evaluate the form preceding point and display the result in a popup buffer.)
Running it has produced a nice popup buffer for me to see the results.

How do I hide this popup buffer? (I don't want to kill it - just get my fullscreen back).

---

FYI Re this command - I've run this with

```
C-h k C-c C-p
```

and got

```
^C ^P runs the command nrepl-pprint-eval-last-expression, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `nrepl.el'.

It is bound to ^C ^P, <menu-bar> <nREPL> <Eval last expression in popup buffer>.

(nrepl-pprint-eval-last-expression)

Evaluate the expression preceding point and pprint its value in a popup buffer.
```

Comment: Either that or just press `q`. I just tried it out with the help buffer and it dismisses the window but not the buffer.
However, popup buffers in the style of ac-nrepl does for its autocompletion are meant to simply be dismissed.

Comment: Thanks @jjpe - please make this into an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either that or just press `q`. I just tried it out with the help buffer and it dismisses the window but not the buffer. However, popup buffers in the style of ac-nrepl does for its autocompletion are meant to simply be dismissed

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information for anyone to test (that's not a standard global binding), and you haven't even indicated whether the new window is selected; but there's a generic solution which will work regardless.

Add `(winner-mode 1)` to your init file, and then you can always use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> to undo the most recent window configuration change (or changes plural, if you repeat the command).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - is there enough info now?

Answer (score 0):

Always, when asking Emacs questions, say what the key sequence does. C-c C-p does nothing here. TO find out what it does press C-h k C-c C-p and report back. In this case we're invoking 'describe-key and then telling it to describe what C-c C-p does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - hopefully there is enough information now.